# android launchMode="singleTop" in two activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my app that have the `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.  It works as expected.

My purposes for having `singleTop` is to update them partially without having to recreate the entire activity from scratch.  A sample execution goes like this.

A -> B

when backpressed from B, display in A is updated.

A -> B -> C

when backpressed from C, display in B is updated.

However, when I flip the display to trigger an orientation change while activity B is on top (from backpressing from C), B is mysteriously destroyed and A is displayed instead.  Why is this happening?  Does android allow more than one activity to have the `singleTop` behavior?  Should I pass other flags from C to B to prevent B from closing if an orientation change happens?

---

Code for above feature:

ActivityA

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra(UPDATE_ARG)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

ActvitiyB

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.putExtra(ActivityA.UPDATE_ARG, true);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra(UPDATE_ARG)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

ActivityC

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra(ActivityB.UPDATE_ARG, true);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in the manifest file, both ActivityA and ActivityB have `android:launchMode="singleTop"` attributes defined.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody's interested, I've managed to implement two singleTop activity behaviors in the app.  But it's working strangely counter-intuitively.

Using the above code, I removed the singleTop attribute for Activity B.

So, when backpressing from Activity C,

A -> B -> C,

backpress then it should be

A -> B -> B,

but for some reasons I don't understand, it's only

A -> B.

It works on 4.2.2.